# array and vector multiplication using threads c language

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm writing a program that uses threads to compute the production of an array by a one dimensional array, all dimensions equal "n".
Each thread must compute the production of a row of the array with that one dimensional array.
The output i'm getting seems to have got addresses values instead of the values i already entered as the matrix elements.
What am i doing wrong?
here's the code i wrote:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define mat_dim 5

static struct param
{
    int mat[mat_dim][mat_dim];
    int vec[mat_dim];
    int ind;
    int alter[mat_dim];
};

void *Calculate_row(struct param tid)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) { 
        tid.alter[tid.ind] = tid.alter[tid.ind]+tid.mat[tid.ind][i]*tid.vec[i];
    }
    pthread_exit((void *)&tid);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread[mat_dim];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int rc;
    long t;
    void *status;
    int th_array[5][5]={{1,4,3,5,1},{4,6,2,8,5},{3,5,1,3,6},{1,5,6,2,8},{4,7,5,3,6}};
    int th_vec[5]={1,2,1,2,1};
    struct param thread_parameter;
    thread_parameter.mat[5][5]=th_array;
    thread_parameter.vec[5]=th_vec;
    int tmp[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
    thread_parameter.alter[5]=tmp;
    /* Initialize and set thread detached attribute */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    for(t=0; t<mat_dim; t++) {
        printf("Main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
        thread_parameter.ind=t;
        rc = pthread_create(&thread[t], &attr, Calculate_row,&thread_parameter); 
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    /* Free attribute and wait for the other threads */
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    printf("the result vector is : ");
    for(t=0; t<mat_dim; t++) {
        rc = pthread_join(thread[t], NULL);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("%d, ",thread_parameter.alter[t]);
    }

    printf("Main: program completed. Exiting.\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: i said that Each thread must compute the production of a row of the array with that one dimensional array. that's the desired behavior. basically i'm modifying the elements of the one dimensional array to become the result array, but the results aren't making any sense. after all, thanks a lot @Antti Haapala

Answer (score 0):

you are calling rc = pthread_create(&thread[t], &attr, Calculate_row,&thread_parameter);
where 
struct param thread_parameter;

and the function is void *Calculate_row(struct param tid)
it should be void *Calculate_row(struct param *tid)
as a pointer is passed and change all . to ->.

Comment: i tried that, didn't help at all. the results are still negative numbers at most, and that doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

All these lines:

```
thread_parameter.mat[5][5]=th_array;
thread_parameter.vec[5]=th_vec;
thread_parameter.alter[5]=tmp;
```

are wrong. The array indexes go from 0 to 4, therefore by addressing the 5th element you're out of their bounds.

You're using `pthread_create` the wrong way. This is the prototype:

```
 int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

Your `Calculate_row` receives a `void*` as a parameter, which needs to be cast to a `(struct param *)` and then dereferenced.

Comment: thanks, but still wrong and these are the values of the resulting array 129100401, -1217300148, -163754450, 0, 1672224820               that's obviously wrong.

Comment: @GhaithMansour See my amended answer. The lines addressing the 5th element of those arrays are wrong. The array indexes go from 0 to 4.